# Building for iOS but linked library was built for MacOS

Tags: c++, ios, macos, g++

I am trying to compile C++ code on Mac using command line tools(g++) to output a static library(.a). I compiled it with architecture support for arm64, however when I link it in Xcode project I get the following error

**Building for iOS but linked library was built for MacOS**

I have used following command

**g++ -shared -o ./libCrossPiOS_TestMulti.iOS.a ./alpha.cpp -arch arm64**

I understand that I can choose XCFrameworks route to get past this but wanted to understand what I'm missing in this approach.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Same problem here. I think is has to do something with the new build system of XCode